# icinga2 to monitor ipsec tunnel on a satelite server

Tags: icinga2

I'm just starting out using icinga2 to monitor some servers. I've managed to set up the hosts I'm monitoring using the node wizard and have the basic stuff working.

I'm now trying to get a test in place where I'm testing a IPSec tunnel on the Satellite host but have hit a knowledge block.

I'm trying to test a ping on a particular address (using the tunnel IP address) to a remote host on the satellite and it looked to me that the fping check was the way to go.

I modified ping4.conf for the particular host in the repositoriy.d/hosts/ directory to be the following

```
object Service "ping4" {
  import "satellite-service"
  check_command = "dummy"
  host_name = "bh.sol.net"
  zone = "bh.sol.net"
}

object Service "fping4" {
  import "satellite-service"
  check_command = "fping4"
  host_name = "bh.sol.net"
  zone = "bh.sol.net"
  vars.fping_address = "10.143.16.225"
  vars.fping_source_ip = "192.168.221.129"
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is

```
ping 10.143.16.225 -I 192.168.221.129
```

which is what I run on the server to test this manually.

I assumed that this new test would be pushed to the satellite server but I can't see any sign of it when I list the objects there, and it has a status of PENDING in the web interface.

I've read through the documentation (or at least started to) and it seems that I'm probably trying to run this test on the icinga host itself not the satellite server (?).

Any pointers on how I run a test on the satellite server like this?

Comment: Have you looked at [NRPE](https://docs.icinga.com/latest/en/nrpe.html)?

Comment: It looks as though NRPE is already installed on the satellite server (must be done by the node wizard I guess. Will have a look at this.

Comment: Any updates to report?